# Onward ticket for boarding a flight to Kathmandu?

Tags: proof-of-onward-travel, kathmandu

Does anyone know whether a proof of onward travel is required for entering Kathmandu by plane (from India for Europeans)?

Answer (score 2):

I flew to KTM from Varanasi, India in 2015. Nothing was required except the passport and USD 25 for the visa. The airline (Air India) checkin didn't care about onward travel plans either. Used my American passport though as they had troubles scanning my European passport at KTM.

Comment: Thanks. Secondarily asked: How does it work to have an American AND an European passport??

Comment: You might post another question and be more specific there. Please do a search first, as we discussed the use of multiple passports extensively before. For example see here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel